# Maximum call stack size exceeded toast.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Estoy intentando setear una funcion en la configuracion del ajax de jquery, para que esta funcion se ejecute cada vez que se mande a llamar un ajax implicitament.

Aqui seteo la funcion que quiero implantar

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(){
        validar_sesion();
    },
});
```

luego es mi ajax que mando llamar en algun lado

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url     : '...',
        data    : {...},
        method  : 'post',
        dataType:"json",
        }).then(resp=>{
              ....
        }).fail(resp=>{
            swal('Ocurrio un problema en la peticion en el servidor, favor de reportar a los administradores', {icon:'error'});
        }).catch(resp=>{
            console.log(resp.responseText);swal('Ocurrio un problema en la peticion en el servidor, favor de reportar a los administradores', {icon:'error'});
        });
```

Esta es la funcion que me pasaron para ejecutar en los ajax implicitamente

```
function validar_sesion(URL = '') {



    $.post(window.origin + '/login/verificar_iniciador', function(data) {

        if (data.length === 2) {
            // showLoading_global('Serás redirigido al Login.');
            // vxalert('info','Serás redirigido al Login.')
            // setTimeout(() => { 
            location.reload();
            // }, 200);

        }

    });


}
```

Y me arroja el siguiente error. Alguien tiene idea de lo que puede estar pasando, porque me dice que la pila esta llena.
toast.js:221 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

```
/**
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Bootstrap (v4.5.0): toast.js
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

import $ from 'jquery'
import Util from './util'

/**
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Constants
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

const NAME               = 'toast'
const VERSION            = '4.5.0'
const DATA_KEY           = 'bs.toast'
const EVENT_KEY          = `.${DATA_KEY}`
const JQUERY_NO_CONFLICT = $.fn[NAME]

const EVENT_CLICK_DISMISS = `click.dismiss${EVENT_KEY}`
const EVENT_HIDE          = `hide${EVENT_KEY}`
const EVENT_HIDDEN        = `hidden${EVENT_KEY}`
const EVENT_SHOW          = `show${EVENT_KEY}`
const EVENT_SHOWN         = `shown${EVENT_KEY}`

const CLASS_NAME_FADE    = 'fade'
const CLASS_NAME_HIDE    = 'hide'
const CLASS_NAME_SHOW    = 'show'
const CLASS_NAME_SHOWING = 'showing'

const DefaultType = {
  animation : 'boolean',
  autohide  : 'boolean',
  delay     : 'number'
}

const Default = {
  animation : true,
  autohide  : true,
  delay     : 500
}

const SELECTOR_DATA_DISMISS = '[data-dismiss="toast"]'

/**
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Class Definition
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

class Toast {
  constructor(element, config) {
    this._element = element
    this._config  = this._getConfig(config)
    this._timeout = null
    this._setListeners()
  }

  // Getters

  static get VERSION() {
    return VERSION
  }

  static get DefaultType() {
    return DefaultType
  }

  static get Default() {
    return Default
  }

  // Public

  show() {
    const showEvent = $.Event(EVENT_SHOW)

    $(this._element).trigger(showEvent)
    if (showEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) {
      return
    }

    if (this._config.animation) {
      this._element.classList.add(CLASS_NAME_FADE)
    }

    const complete = () => {
      this._element.classList.remove(CLASS_NAME_SHOWING)
      this._element.classList.add(CLASS_NAME_SHOW)

      $(this._element).trigger(EVENT_SHOWN)

      if (this._config.autohide) {
        this._timeout = setTimeout(() => {
          this.hide()
        }, this._config.delay)
      }
    }

    this._element.classList.remove(CLASS_NAME_HIDE)
    Util.reflow(this._element)
    this._element.classList.add(CLASS_NAME_SHOWING)
    if (this._config.animation) {
      const transitionDuration = Util.getTransitionDurationFromElement(this._element)

      $(this._element)
        .one(Util.TRANSITION_END, complete)
        .emulateTransitionEnd(transitionDuration)
    } else {
      complete()
    }
  }

  hide() {
    if (!this._element.classList.contains(CLASS_NAME_SHOW)) {
      return
    }

    const hideEvent = $.Event(EVENT_HIDE)

    $(this._element).trigger(hideEvent)
    if (hideEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) {
      return
    }

    this._close()
  }

  dispose() {
    clearTimeout(this._timeout)
    this._timeout = null

    if (this._element.classList.contains(CLASS_NAME_SHOW)) {
      this._element.classList.remove(CLASS_NAME_SHOW)
    }

    $(this._element).off(EVENT_CLICK_DISMISS)

    $.removeData(this._element, DATA_KEY)
    this._element = null
    this._config  = null
  }

  // Private

  _getConfig(config) {
    config = {
      ...Default,
      ...$(this._element).data(),
      ...typeof config === 'object' && config ? config : {}
    }

    Util.typeCheckConfig(
      NAME,
      config,
      this.constructor.DefaultType
    )

    return config
  }

  _setListeners() {
    $(this._element).on(EVENT_CLICK_DISMISS, SELECTOR_DATA_DISMISS, () => this.hide())
  }

  _close() {
    const complete = () => {
      this._element.classList.add(CLASS_NAME_HIDE)
      $(this._element).trigger(EVENT_HIDDEN)
    }

    this._element.classList.remove(CLASS_NAME_SHOW)
    if (this._config.animation) {
      const transitionDuration = Util.getTransitionDurationFromElement(this._element)

      $(this._element)
        .one(Util.TRANSITION_END, complete)
        .emulateTransitionEnd(transitionDuration)
    } else {
      complete()
    }
  }

  // Static

  static _jQueryInterface(config) {
    return this.each(function () {
      const $element = $(this)
      let data       = $element.data(DATA_KEY)
      const _config  = typeof config === 'object' && config

      if (!data) {
        data = new Toast(this, _config)
        $element.data(DATA_KEY, data)
      }

      if (typeof config === 'string') {
        if (typeof data[config] === 'undefined') {
          throw new TypeError(`No method named "${config}"`)
        }

        data[config](this)
      }
    })
  }
}

/**
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * jQuery
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

$.fn[NAME]             = Toast._jQueryInterface
$.fn[NAME].Constructor = Toast
$.fn[NAME].noConflict  = () => {
  $.fn[NAME] = JQUERY_NO_CONFLICT
  return Toast._jQueryInterface
}

export default Toast
```

Comment: ¿y ese toast.js de donde sale?

Comment: por alguna razon es el modulo que importa al contexto global el jquery en la aplicacion. Es un script que se importa globalmente y el que detona el error. Voy a poner el codigo en la pregunta.

Comment: Y por qué tienes que validar la sesión en el beforeSend!? Al final estás haciendo dos peticiones al lado del servidor, una para validar la sesión y la otra para solicitar la información como tal, y ahí lo más seguro es que no estés validando la sesión. Entendiste!?

Comment: Te entendi. Mira el punto es que esa funcion la usan todos aqui, antes de cada ajax mandan a llamar esa funcion. si la Funcion validarsession detecta que no hay sesion, entonces refresca la pantalla y el sistema lo manda al login. Como la mayoria de las pantallas son puras peticiones ajax, nunca se recarga la pantalla.
Entonces queria ver algun modo de que esa funcion o crear una nueva en la que cada que se mande un ajax al servidor primero valide que halla session, si es asi deja pasar el ajax, si no entonces no lo deja pasar y lo regresa al login. Pero que ese implicito en los request